# Sending a pipe as an argument to an external program in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I keep getting the following error when running a command to look for the most recently modified directory in my path: remotely from PowerShell:

head: The term 'head' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

```
At line 1: char: 95
+ ... d /somedir ; (lastmod=$(ls -tda -- */ | head -n 1); ....
```

I'm running code something along the lines of the following:

```
& plink "bob@server" "cd /somedir ; (lastmod=$(ls -tda -- */ | head -n 1); ls -la $lastmod)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encapsulated your commands in double-quotes so the  `$` signs are being expanded by PowerShell. If you use single quotes this won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on to Bruce's answer, you could also escape the special character from your double-quoted string using the grave accent (`), which is the escape character in powershell.

```
& plink "bob@server" "cd /somedir ; (lastmod=$(ls -tda -- */ `| head -n 1); ls -la $lastmod)"
```

This means that if you did need any variables inside of your string, you could still utilize special characters.